# Connecting multiple tables and using self join

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a problem regarding a mysql query. What I'm supposed to do is find the pair of actors that acted in most of films together.

I have 3 tables:

`actor - has id and name`

`casting - has movieid, actorid and ord`

`movie - has id (own id, not the one from actor), title, year, score, votes and director.`

So, I did the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT a.actorid,
b.actorid,
c.name,
d.name,
COUNT(*) AS zajednicka_pojavljivanja
FROM casting a,
casting b,
actor c,
actor d,
WHERE a.movieid=b.movieid AND a.actorid<>b.actorid
GROUP BY a.actorid,b.actorid,c.name,d.name) tablica_temp
ORDER BY zajednicka_pojavljivanja DESC;
```

What I get is an error:

ERROR

> 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'WHERE  a.movieid=b.movieid AND a.actorid<>b.actorid GROUP BY
>   a.actorid) tablica_t' at line 1

I don't know where the problem is, can anyone help?

Comment: Well the comma after `actor D` is wrong but I've not looked into if this will give the results you're after.

Comment: In casting table, do you have actor_id for the 2 leading roles per movie or there can be many actors per movie in the casting table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close.  The <> on your original query simply needed to be set to < or > but not <>  and then you needed to limit your results or use a select max(count) approach to get all of the same counts.

```
SELECT A.ActorID, B.ActorID, Count(*) MostFilms
FROM Casting A
INNER JOIN Casting B
 ON A.MovieID = B.MovieID and A.ActorID < B.ActorID
Group by A.ActorID, B.ActorID
order by MostFilms Desc
Limit 1
```

Basically what this says is join casting to itself getting the paired actors by movie.  the < on A.ActorID to B.ActorID eliminates actor to him/herself and the opposites so if Actor A and B exist, B to A will not be included.
ordering by the MostFilms descending will return only that pair with the most.
The downfall to this is if two pairs have the same count only one of them would be returned.

If you need the names of the actors you can add two joins one for each casting table.

Comment: @Juraj  Thanks for putting forth effort on your own first.  you were very close just needed a nudge in 2 places!

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra comma in the FROM clause.  Change:

```
actor d,
```

to

```
actor d
```